# Purposes of Ubuntu 18.04's .css files

Tags: gnome, themes

Can you tell me what are the purposes of these files in comparison to the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`?

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-classic.css
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-classic-high-contrast.css
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu-high-contrast.css
```

Also, how and when are they activated after Ubuntu 18.04 is boot up?

I know that `ubuntu.css` is used to define the appearance of Ubuntu's loginscreen, unlockscreen, lockscreen, and certain aspect of it's desktop.

Thanks.

Comment: They are different themes.. And also some are not installed by default.. Their purpose is to have different look for gnome-shell and any one theme file is must to run gnome-shell

Comment: @YuganTej How or when are these themes `gnome-shell.css`, `gnome-classic.css` and `gnome-classic-high-contrast.css` activated? Also, am I correct to think that `ubuntu-high-contrast.css` is activated when I click on Ubuntu's loginscreen top right corner drop down menu `High-Contrast` toggle switch?

Comment: You can configure any theme you want out of the files you mentioned.. For high contrast I am not sure is it from built in or from other hidden file..